# How to combine 2 past future perfect tenses?

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

> 1. I would have had practical experience.
> 2. The practical experience would have been improved.

Is it correct to combine them like this:

> **I would have had practical experience that would have been improved.**

Or can this be written succinctly as follows?:

> **I would have had practical experience that improved.**

I'm not sure about the second becuase it sounds ambiguous to me. People might think "That improved" is something that has already improved (in the past). And about the first, can we really use would two times in a sentence? Or do you have another alternative to combine those two sentences? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two sentences are slightly contradictory. The sentence

> The practical experience would have been improved.

implies that a practical experience would exist prior to the improvement. So I already have a practical experience and in a certain situation ***it would have been improved***. However this contradicts what the first sentence says

> I would have had practical experience.

which implies that I don't have practical experience.

So let's say it is a bit confusing. If you are to keep the best of the two sentences, I would probably say:

> I would have had an improved practical experience.

or

> I would have acquired an improved practical experience.